# Does my pseudocode have any issues in it?

Tags: pseudocode

So the problem this time around deals with charge account validation. Basically, we have to design a program in pseudocode where a user enters an account number, and the program validates it by comparing it to a list we are to put in an array. The numbers should be stored in the array, and we are required to use the sequential search algorithm to locate the number entered by the user. If the number is in the array, the program displays a message indicating it is valid. If not, it displays, invalid. There is a requirement of the main module, and the function isTicketValid. I was wondering if my pseudocode was proper. Thanks!

```
    Constant Integer SIZE = 18
    Declare String account[SIZE] = "5658845", "4520125", "7895122", 8777541",                           "8451277", "1302850", "8080152", "4562555", "5552012", "5050552", "7825877", "1250255",      "1005231", "6545231", "3852085", "7576651", "7881200", "4581002"

    Module main()
          Display "Please enter your charge account number"
          Input account
          isValidAccount(account)
    Main()

    Function Integer isValidAccount(account)
    Declare Boolean found
    Declare Integer index
    Set found = False
    Set index = 0
    While found == False AND index <= SIZE -1
          If account[index] == account Then
                Set found = True 
          Else
                Set index = index + 1
          End if
    End While
    If found Then
          Display "Your account is valid ", index + 1
    Else
          Display "Your account is not valid."
    End If
    End Function
```

Comment: This isn't pseudocode.  It's VB, or at least so close to VB that a compiler would give you messages about a few fixable syntax errors.  :P  You're kinda missing the point about pseudocode; it is a slightly higher-level description, for people first and foremost, and is generally not worried about declaring variables or caring about their types.  That crap is for the compiler.

Comment: Ah, i'm just going off of the textbook's pseudocode format haha

Comment: It might be better to ask this question on codereview - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/